# I want to loop 100 times but not print 100 times in the loop (Python)

Tags: python, loops, random, printing

```
for lp in range(100):
    if guess == number:
        break
    if guess < number:
        print "Nah m8, Higher."
    else:
        print "Nah m8, lower."
```

This is some basic code that I was told to make for a basic computing class. My aim is to make a simple 'game' where the user has to guess a random number that the computer has picked (1-100) This is a small section of the code where I want to continue checking if the guess is equal to, lower or higher than the number; but if I put a print statement below, it will print the text 100 times. How can I remove this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

It seems like you're omitting the guessing stage. Where is the program asking the user for input?

Ask them at the beginning of the loop!

```
for lp in range(100):
    guess = int(input('Guess number {0}:'.format(lp + 1)))
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a new input each time through your loop; otherwise you just keep checking the same things.

```
for lp in range(100):
    if guess == number:
        break
    if guess < number:
        # Get a new guess!
        guess = int(raw_input("Nah m8, Higher."))
    else:
        # Get a new guess!
        guess = int(raw_input("Nah m8, lower."))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for a guess inside the loop:

```
while True:
    guess = int(raw_input("Guess: "))
    if guess == number:
        break
    if guess < number:
        print "Nah m8, Higher."
    else:
        print "Nah m8, lower."
```

Comment: You should use `raw_input`. Otherwise fun things can happen (`Guess: __import__('os').system('rm -rf *')`)...

Comment: sorry, I am used to python 3 where this does not exist ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
number = 0

x = []
while number < 100:
    guess = random.randint(1,100)

    if number < guess:
        print(f 'Number {number} is less than guess {guess}')
    elif number > guess:
        print(f 'Number {number} is greater than guess {guess}')
    number += 1
```

This will work for you